# How to determine if Cesium map has been fully loaded in Canvas?

Tags: java, selenium, automation, maps, cesiumjs

I'm an automation tester, and I'd like to know if there is a way to make sure that the cesium map is fully loaded in the canvas before running any tests on it.

I have not written any code till now as I didn't find anything [via dev tools] which I can use in my code.

For testing purpose you can use this [URL](https://sandcastle.cesium.com/?src=Cesium%20Widget.html%5D).

It would be helpful if you could offer me some insight on how to achieve the above task, or if you could also point me in the right direction. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How would you know that manually ?

Comment: I can verify that visually. But need to know how can I achieve it programmatically. If you go to my provided URL you can see that globe is taking some time to show up. I would just like to make sure that it is loaded fully then only i will start performing other tests. One more problem is that cesium map is loading in canvas tag which is not giving any indication of 'loading map' or so.

Comment: yes that's true, I see 2 canvas tag. none of them actually have any info about globe. When you right click and try to inspect on it, you won't see anything. Strange !

Comment: what it the meaning of "full loaded"?

Comment: @ZhefengJin "fully loaded" means the globe should be clearly loaded in the canvas because Sometimes it takes time to load.

Comment: Is there any update on this issue? Do you find any solution?

Comment: @TekKshetri Nope.